# 2006 Subaru outback station wagon

Tags: gears, steering-wheel, ignition-key

I have 2006 subaru outback station wagon,my key wont turn the steering wheel is lock and the gears wont change and ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the steering wheel at an odd angle and completely locked? Have you tried jiggling it a little bit while you attempt to turn the key? Could be the steering wheel is hard over onto the locking mechanism and is not allowing it to turn.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 giggling at your "giggling" . . . can I buy a "J"?

Comment: @SteveRacer - Okay, okay ... I still make that mistake ;-) Thanks for pointing it out!